# Import all files in directory without having to explicitly specify each file

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

I want to import all components that reside in a folder. Is there a way to do this without having to create an `index.js` file and individually importing and then exporting each component? Is there a bulk way?

Folder structure:

```
src/templates/
             Foo.vue
             Bar.vue
             Baz.vue
src/App.vue
```

In App.vue I would like to import all components in `templates` folder:

```
import * as Templates from './templates'
```

The above doesn't work unless I place an `index.js` file in `./templates` folder:

```
// Do I have to import each component individually?
// Can I just bulk import all these?

import Default from './Default'
import Home from './Home'
import Agency from './Agency' 
import CaseStudies from './CaseStudies'
import Contact from './Contact'

export {
    Default,
    Home,
    Agency,
    CaseStudies,
    Contact
}
```

Comment: Maybe babel-wildcard could help https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-wildcard ?

Comment: Maybe you could have phrased it as "Import wild card single file component Vue files does not work". People who downvoted it probably don't know that is a specific file type. I upvoted it, it's a valid question.

Comment: I think this works if you use `Templates.Foo or Templates.Bar`

Answer (score 5):

You can do bulk import

```
import { Default, Home, Agency, CaseStudies, Contact } from "./templates/*";
```

with [babel-plugin-wildcard](https://github.com/vihanb/babel-plugin-wildcard)

.babelrc

```
  "plugins": [
    "transform-vue-jsx",
    "transform-runtime",
    ["wildcard", {
      "exts": ["js", "es6", "es", "jsx", "javascript", "vue"]
    }]
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `require.context`,you can read vuejs official doc: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Answer (score -3):

You can use async import():

import fs = require('fs');

and then:

```
fs.readdir('./someDir', (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
      const module = import('./' + file).then(m =>
        m.callSomeMethod();
      );
      // or const module = await import('file')
  });
});
```

Comment: This only works if you are using vue server side. In the browser you don't have access to the `fs` module

Comment: Yes this is for server side only (Node.js.